# How to use LINQ to determine if specific attribute value exists?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am programming in C# and working with an XDocument. 
Want to add an element into the tree if and only if there are no other elements that have the a matching attribute value.

For example, is there a LINQ expression that I can use to look at the element below and see if there already exists a foo element with the same name before I add it?

```
<people>
    <foo Name="Bob"> </foo>
    <foo Name="Larry"></foo>
    <foo Name="Tom"></foo>
</people>
```

I want to do something like this...

```
while(myXDocument.Element("people").Elements("foo").Attribute("Name").Contains(myName))
{
    // modify myName and then try again...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
XElement.Any(element => element.Attribute("Name").Value == myName)
```

It will return true if there's an attribute `Name` that equals `myName`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it was very useful! But, you wrote "=" instead of "==", didn't you?

Comment: Indeed I did, as a VB guy it's sometimes hard to switch over to c#

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [IEnumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) on the XDocument.Elements. This determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.